# Is there a way to make Pubsubclient libary compatible with PlatformIO?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mqtt, platformio, unity-test-framework

For a project where I need to unit test my code with which I receive data from a mqtt server with the Pubsubclient library via an ESP32. I want to use platformio which uses the Unity testing framework. When running my tests I get following Errormsg:

```
Framework incompatible library C:\Users\**\Dokumente\PlatformIO\Projects\230716-174800-ttgo-t1\lib\EspMQTTClient
Framework incompatible library C:\Users\**\Dokumente\PlatformIO\Projects\230716-174800-ttgo-t1\lib\PubSubClient
```

Is there a MQTT library which is compatible with unity or is there a way to make it work with my chosen libs?

Tried unit testing, unity doesn't want to work with my library it seems.
Tried to turn of library comp mode in the platformio.ini, but that changed nothing.
testing in general works for example with a simple add function. but as soon as I start using libraries it won't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.